# Signal handler with threads

Tags: signals

If I have a program with two threads and a signal handler registered on signum which prints something.  How many times will it be printed if I send the signal signum to my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming a Unix or Unix-like system. Only one of the threads gets the signal. From TLPI:

> When a signal is delivered to a multithreaded process that has
>   established a sig- nal handler, the kernel arbitrarily **selects one
>   thread in the process to which to deliver the signal** and invokes the
>   handler in that thread.

Comment: Can't blame you, I'm also ignoring Microsoft existence :-)

Comment: I think it's also important to say that with `pthread_sigmask` you can control which threads receive which signals. Using this you can effectively control to which thread your signal will be delivered.